# label of subfigures

Tags: subfloats, labels

how to write label like this Fig. 1(a) instead of Fig .1a in text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,aps,12pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{floatrow}   
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}   


\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts} %for \mathfrak & \mathbb
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm,left=1.5cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {myfigures/} }
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]%prints every 5 lines
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\footnotesize\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{hyperref} %To hyperlink
\hypersetup{
colorlinks=true,
linkcolor=blue,
filecolor=magenta,      
urlcolor=cyan,
citecolor=blue
 }    
\usepackage{placeins} % for \FloatBarrier
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{.6cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}% line spacing for first line in paragraph 
\newcommand{\Author}[2][2]{\begin{center}{{#1, #2}}\end{center}}
\def\Faculty#1#2{\begin{center}{{#1}}, {#2}\end{center}}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\DeclareCaptionJustification{justified}{\justifying} 
\captionsetup{justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false, position=top, labelfont=large, labelformat=simple}  
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
      \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{1a.pdf}   \label{fig:figzoda}}\\[-30pt]
      \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{1b.pdf}   \label{fig:figzodb}}\\[-30pt]
      \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{1c.pdf}   \label{fig:figzodc}}


    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use subcaption instead of subfig, you will have more control over the formatting.  Or you could just use minipages and write your own captions.

Answer (score 2):

Per default the reference to sub-figures will be the letter only (for example "a") and the caption labels will be surrounded by parenthesis. So if you want to move the parenthesis to the reference, one need to change this by adding them to the generic display format and remove them from the caption label format, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,aps,12pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage[caption=false,labelformat=simple]{subfig}
  % "labelformat=simple" removes the parenthesis from the caption label
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
  % This one adds parenthesis to the display format

\begin{document}
\ref{fig:figzoda} % Prints now "1(a)"
\begin{figure}[h]\centering
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{1a.pdf}   \label{fig:figzoda}}
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{1b.pdf}   \label{fig:figzodb}}
      \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{1c.pdf}   \label{fig:figzodc}}
      \caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Please note that I added the option `caption=false` when loading the `subfig` package (and dropped the explicit loading of the `caption` package) since the `caption` package is currently not fully compatible to the RevTeX document class:

```
Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```